# Massive API/Framework mashup issue (oAuth, Facebook, Twitter, Code Igniter)

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, get, uri

I'm having (many, but for now,) one problem with a project I'm working on.

1. It is a PHP project run on Code Igniter
2. It is a Facebook app that wants to use oAuth Twitter authorization

CodeIgniter by default clears the $_GET array because it uses the URI for controlling MVC stuff. You can turn this off to access the GET array, and use a string like `example.com/?c=MyController&m=MyMethod` to get around this.

Facebook asks you to define a root url for you application page. This means that for me:

```
apps.facebook.com/MyApplication == http://www.myownserver.com/index.php/c=SignIn&
```

I have it set up this way so that it can use the $_GET array. When Twitter (and I assume any other implementation) uses oAuth, it passes back to whatever URL you want with the `?token=250937602736037609273609327` appended onto the end, so I end up at

```
app.facebook.com/MyApplication/?token=302870637602746094276097
```

which looks right, but is in fact equivalent to

```
http://www.myownserver.com/index.php/c=SignIn&?token=302870637602746094276097
```

So the problem is that you can't have two question marks in the URL; the second needs to be an ampersand (&) to string more values together. The error message is a predictable `Disallowed Key Characters.`

Can anyone thing of a good/clever way to get around this issue I'm having? I really don't want to dump the CodeIgniter part of this setup because it has a great DB abstraction and good helpers that I've already written a good bit of code on.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Can you do something clever with mod_rewrite and the QSA flag to automatically string it together, perhaps? I.e. have a rewrite for your 'root url' instead of tacking the ampersand onto it in facebook?

Comment: Dav is correct, the easiest way would be to rewrite the url BEFORE it gets processed by the url parser of codeigniter (in fact with mod_rewrite you should be able to rewrite both the url and the query string)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't fully understand your problem, but can't you add `&` to `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in the application/config/config.php file?

Comment: Well, the problem is that proper forming of the GET array looks like "?field=value&field2=value2&field3=value3". The symbols go "?&&&&..." and this results in "??&&&&&" So it knows that ampersands are ok, but the issue is having TWO question marks in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the Input Library to allow query strings and pretty urls.

Check out [haughin.com](http://haughin.com) for the Twitter Library, and see how he did it.